# Issue in displaying Unicoded native language characters through MFC in Windows XP

Tags: unicode, fonts, mfc, windows-xp

I'm trying to display Unicode Bengali, a native language of India through a MFC application as below:

```
CFont *m_pFontSmallBN = new CFont();
m_pFontSmallBN->CreateFont(34,0,0,0,600,0,0,0,ANSI_CHARSET,OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
            CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,DEFAULT_QUALITY,DEFAULT_PITCH|FF_DONTCARE,
            _T("Ekushey Lalsalu")); //"Ekushey Lalsalu" is the Bengali Font name here. 
CStatic m_msg_bn;
m_msg_bn.SetFont(m_pFontSmallBN,TRUE);
m_msg_bn.SetWindowText(_T("TEXT IN NATIVE LANGUAGE")); //TEXT is typed with the Font
```

While I'm running the app in Windows vista it can display the text perfectly; but in Windows XP it cannot display unicode characters properly. Compound alphabets (framed with multiple unicode characters) of the bengali language are being displayed as separate characters. I ensured that both Windows Vista and XP have the Font installed and character set of my MFC project setting is Unicode.

Could anybody please help me to find out the issue in Windows XP environment ?

Comment: ANSI_CHARSET?  Are you sure that is really what you want?

Comment: Using LOGFONT properties of the specific font I got nCharSet as 0. So I tried with passing ANSI_CHARSET as its defined as 0. I also tried with value 1 but no luck. What value would you suggest me to use in place of nCharSet? I'm bit confused on the behavior of same Font on XP and Vista/Win 7 environment. Any clue on the issue would help me lot.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing a font in Windows is tricky. You'd expect the font name to take precedence over all other font characteristics, but that's not always the case. To be sure you're getting the proper font you should make sure *all* the parameters to [`CreateFont`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183499(v=vs.85).aspx) match the font you want. This article, though old, details the font mapping process: [Windows Font Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms969909.aspx).

Here's a small program that puts up a font selection dialog and dumps the parameters that you can pass to `CreateFont` to guarantee that you're getting the font you want.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
   LOGFONT lf = {};
   CHOOSEFONT cf = {sizeof(CHOOSEFONT)};
   cf.lpLogFont = &lf;
   cf.Flags = CF_BOTH | CF_FORCEFONTEXIST;
   if (ChooseFont(&cf))
   {
      wprintf(L"%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,", lf.lfHeight, lf.lfWidth, lf.lfEscapement, lf.lfOrientation, lf.lfWeight);
      wprintf(L"%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,", lf.lfItalic, lf.lfUnderline, lf.lfStrikeOut, lf.lfCharSet, lf.lfOutPrecision);
      wprintf(L"%d,%d,%d,", lf.lfClipPrecision, lf.lfQuality, lf.lfPitchAndFamily);
      wprintf(L"_T(\"%s\")\n", lf.lfFaceName);
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I run the above program on Win XP or Vista, it raises "There is no fonts installed. Open the fonts folder from the control panel to install fonts" although a lot of Fonts are installed there. However, I got the properties of the specific Font on Win 7. Passing the same values to create the font didn't make any change in Win XP.

Comment: @Sukhendu I added a flag that probably makes a difference for XP, try it with the mod and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In windows vista just I checked with the modified one; this time it ran successfully. The values are same as that of Win 7 environment. 14 properties are: -13,0,0,0,700,0,0,0,0,3,2,1,2,_T(“Ekushey Lalsalu”). At this moment I've no XP environment with me therefore, I've to wait until tomorrow to check it. But I'm surprised that even after passing the same values, the MFC application couldn't display Bengali Chars perfectly. May be this is due to wrong params. I'll confirm you the status tomorrow after extracting those params and using the same for Font creation in XP environment.

Comment: @Sukhendu make sure you run the program on XP too, to see if there are any parameters that are different.

Comment: Yes, I'll run the program on XP and use the same values for CreateFont parameters.

Answer (score 0):

@Mark I could not add my comment using "add a comment" link; therefore, I'm adding it here. Even in XP environment the program displays same values for the Font properties. Another thing is that using notepad of the same system, I see the same improper display. It can display bengali font but display is improper for compound alphabet (consonant conjunct or consonant attached with a diacritic form of a vowel) of bengali language. This is probably due to XP doesn't have in-built support for complex text for native scripts like bengali by default. Windows from Vista and onward have this complex text support enabled by default; therefore just installing a native unicode font enables us to view native script properly.